# increasing the billnumber for a year and reset it to 1 again in new year

Tags: sql

I have tried this -

```
SELECT top(1)billreference
FROM BIll
WHERE datepart(yy,date)=datepart(yy,getdate())
ORDER BY billreference DESC
```

it is always returning me `9` when I have incremented by `1`

i want to increase the `billrefernece number` by 1 as it is not `identity` column 
i am doing this coz i have to reset it to `1` after the change in `year`  and increase throughout that year..
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Share sample data, desired output and DBMS you are using

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the question that your table have data in `date` column as below.

```
      date1
-------------------
01.01.2016 00:00:00
01.01.2016 00:00:00
01.01.2016 00:00:00
01.01.2016 00:00:00
01.01.2017 00:00:00
01.01.2017 00:00:00
01.01.2017 00:00:00
01.01.2017 00:00:00
```

and you want to return `billreference` incremented  by 1 for the same year and reset it when `year` changes, below query can be an option in `sql-server`.

```
SELECT row_number() over(partition BY datepart(yy,date1)
                         ORDER BY date1) AS billreference,
       date1
FROM t1;
```

for other `dbms`, ANSI standard `extract(year from datecolumn)` can be used instead of `datepart`

**Result:**

```
billreference        date1
-----------------------------------
1              01.01.2016 00:00:00
2              01.01.2016 00:00:00
3              01.01.2016 00:00:00
4              01.01.2016 00:00:00
1              01.01.2017 00:00:00
2              01.01.2017 00:00:00
3              01.01.2017 00:00:00
4              01.01.2017 00:00:00
```

You  can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/LDLF29463)**